# Android Studio - Genymotion - Connected Device - Not Showing Up

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I have installed Genymotion. I have installed Android Studio. I have also got the Genymotion icon showing in android Studio by doing:

To install the Genymotion plugin for Android Studio

1. In Android Studio, go to File/Settings (for Windows and Linux) or to Android Studio/Preferences (for Mac OS X)
2. Select Plugins and click Browse Repositories.
3. Right-click on Genymotion and click Download and install. To see Genymotion plugin icon, display the toolbar by clicking View > Toolbar.

I get the Genymotion Virtual Device up and running in the backgroud, it looks great.

So now I click the 'Play' button in Andoid Studio to debug my code. It goes to the 'Select Deployment Target' dialog box, but my running Genymotion device is not there.

**How can I get my Genymotion Virtual Android device showing in this dialog?**